# WSUS and windows update make clients PC very slow

Tags: windows-7, wsus, bits

At our office, there is a WSUS server that distributes windows updates to every client PC (Windows 7) between 1:00pm and 2:00pm. The problem is that he PCs become very slow during that time.

Is there any way to accelerate this process?

What should we look to solve this problem?

Could downloading be the problem or could be the update process itself?

Comment: How about changing the time that the clients install updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than accelerate the process i would suggest that the oposite is needed to maintain performance.

It could be that [BITS (Background Inteligent Transfer Service)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is downloading manny updates from the WSUS server and swapming the network at this time.

You could try limiting the bandwidth the client PC's are using by setting up a group policy to do so.

take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the details